# AWS Lambda python to send an email body as HTML from the response of DynamoDB events

Tags: python, html, amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda

We are trying to create an AWS Lambda function to create an email with HTML body to alert the teams regarding the records which are changed.

To achieve this we have created a Lambda function with Python that captures the variables from the response of event and passes to HTML. My code below has problem in regarding the variable from HTML to python. Can you please help to me fix it?

Since the email out is just the string mentioned in the HTML. In general I should get the variable which is assigned to it.

```py
import boto3
import json
from datetime import datetime
import smtplib  
import email.utils
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #print(event)
    RecordInfo = event['Records']
    RecordDetails = RecordInfo[0]
    EventName = RecordDetails['eventName']

    Dyna = RecordDetails['dynamodb']
    Modtime = Dyna['ApproximateCreationDateTime']
    ModifiedTime=datetime.fromtimestamp(Modtime).strftime("%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")


    if (EventName == 'MODIFY'):

        OldData = Dyna['OldImage']
        OldAppKey=OldData['Application']
        OldApp=OldAppKey['S']

        OldAppServerKey=OldData['App_Server']
        OldAppServer=OldAppServerKey['S']

        OldAppUserKey=OldData['App_User']
        OldAppUser=OldAppUserKey['S']

        OldAppIPKey=OldData['App_IP']
        OldAppIP=OldAppIPKey['S']

        OldAppPwdKey=OldData['App_Pwd']
        OldAppPwd=OldAppPwdKey['S']

        OldAppPortKey=OldData['App_Port']
        OldAppPort=OldAppPortKey['S']

        #If Eventname is 'Modify' then above inserted value of Sub will be overridden
        # The subject line of the email.
        SUBJECT = "Table Name:DBTest - Updated on " + ModifiedTime

        Message1 = Message1 + "\nOld Record Details:\n" + "Application:" + OldApp + "\tApp_IP:" + OldAppIP + "\tApp_User:" + OldAppUser + "\tApp_Pwd:" + OldAppPwd + "\tApp_Port:" + OldAppPort
        # The HTML body of the email.
        BODY_HTML = BODY_HTML + print ("

        Old Record Details:

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>html title</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            table{
                background-color: #AAD373;
                empty-cells:hide;
            }
            td.cell{
                background-color: white;
            }
        </style>

        <table style="border: black 1px solid;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">Application</td>
            <td class="cell">App_IP</td>
            <td class="cell">App_User</td>
            <td class="cell">App_Pwd</td>
            <td class="cell">App_Port</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">{OldApp}</td>
            <td class="cell">{OldAppIP}</td>
            <td class="cell">{OldAppUser}</td>
            <td class="cell">{OldAppPwd}</td>
            <td class="cell">{OldAppPort}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        ")


    # The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
    BODY_TEXT = (Message1)

    SENDER = 'xx'  
    SENDERNAME = 'AWS DynamoDB Alert'
    RECIPIENT  = 'xx'
    USERNAME_SMTP = "XX"
    PASSWORD_SMTP = "xx/xx"
    # (Optional) the name of a configuration set to use for this message
    HOST = "email-smtp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
    PORT = 25
    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr((SENDERNAME, SENDER))
    msg['To'] = RECIPIENT

    part1 = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(BODY_HTML, 'html')

    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    try:  
        server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST, PORT)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()

        server.ehlo()
        server.login(USERNAME_SMTP, PASSWORD_SMTP)
        server.sendmail(SENDER, RECIPIENT, msg.as_string())
        server.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print ("Error: ", e)
    else:
        print ("Email sent!")
```

Comment: 1: there's no lambda function here(something like: `foo = lambda x: x * x`) and i would suggest a regular function to do this anyway. 2: please provide more info than "my code has problem", to actually help you we would need: expected behaviour of the code and what it is doing instead(error messages etc).

Comment: Hey @garglblarg.. I was referring to AWS lambda.. not the lambda of python .. in the code when it execute it the table should get the variable passed to 'OldApp' but it started sending OldApp text in the email..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you want to have strings like this substitute the variables:

```
<td class="cell">{OldApp}</td>
```

To do this in Python 3.6+, you should use an `f-string`, such as:

```
BODY_HTML = f"...<td class="cell">{OldApp}</td>..."
```

Note the `f` before the opening quote, which tells Python to substitute expressions contained within `{curly brackets}`.

Also, the `print()` statement should *not* be in this variable assignment:

```
BODY_HTML = BODY_HTML + print ("...
```

Another few tips..

You can shorten this:

```
RecordInfo = event['Records']
RecordDetails = RecordInfo[0]
EventName = RecordDetails['eventName']
```

into:

```
EventName = event['Records'][0]['eventName']
```

Similarly, you could shorten:

```
OldAppIPKey=OldData['App_IP']
OldAppIP=OldAppIPKey['S']
```

into:

```
OldAppIP=OldData['App_IP']['S']
```

Comment: thank you for explaining this.. i tried the approach you suggested me..But still could not reach it.. can you please see what went wrong..'''   BODY_HTML = """
        <tr>
            f...<td class="cell">{App}</td>...</tr>
            
             """

Comment: and tried other way..   BODY_HTML =f"...
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">{OldApp}</td>
            <td class="cell">{OldAppIP}</td>
            <td class="cell">{OldAppUser}</td>
            <td class="cell">{OldAppPwd}</td>
            <td class="cell">{OldAppPort}</td>
        </tr>
        ..." also

Comment: Use `BODY_HTML = f'...<td class="cell">...{OldApp}...'` The single quote allows double quotes to be inside.

Comment: Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': EOL while scanning string literal .. it throws errors

Comment: Okay, use `BODY_HTML = f'''...<td class="cell">...{OldApp}...'''` The three quotes will allow it to go over multiple lines, and seems to work with the f-string prefix.